# What is the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: meaning

In about good habit & bad, I run into the sentence like

> Doing something over and over again until you don't have to think about **it is how actions become habitual in the first place**

Could you explain more easier expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the appropriate commas clarifies the sentence.

> Doing something over and over again, until you don't have to think about it, is how actions become habitual in the first place.

Though a much simpler statement would be

> Repetition instills habit.

Answer (score 2):

Reforming the original sentence into these two sentences may help you understand the original sentence:

> Repetition is doing something over and
>   over again until you don't have to
>   think about it.
>
> That is how actions become habitual in
>   the first place.